# There is always "Application isn't running.(-600)" where I use applescript in my Mac App

Tags: swift, macos, applescript

I want to use Applescript to help my App open a new Window of iTerm. Here is my code:

```
public func runScript(_ name: String, args: [String]) {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "tools", ofType: "scpt")!
    Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: "/usr/bin/osascript", arguments: [path])
}
```

with Applescript:

```
tell application "iTerm" to create window with default profile
tell application "iTerm" to tell the first window to tell current session to write text "echo Hello World"
```

And there is an error: "Application isn't running. (-600)"
But this script can run perfectly in Terminal. I don't know why.

Comment: Is the app sandboxed? If yes you cannot use `Process`. And you need to specify the key `NSAppleEventsUsageDescription` in Info.plist

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.☆*･゜ﾟ･(^O^)/･゜ﾟ･*☆